# .NET System.Security.Cryptography is very slow for AES Encryption/Decryption of small strings

Tags: .net, vb.net, encryption

I am using a slightly adapted version of this VB.NET code to encrypt and decrypt small strings:
http://programmers-en.high-way.info/vb/aes.html

It uses the System.Security.Cryptography library with 128 BITS AES CBC.

(I do always change the initialization vector, and the key is stored encrypted of course)

I notice that AES in .NET is pretty slow for encrypting small strings, if I decrypt a small string (about 20 characters) a 100.000 times on a fast notebook that takes about 12 seconds (timed with .net StopWatch). An abysmal throughput rate to be sure.

Is there a .NET way to encrypt/decrypt individual (small) strings really quickly?

Code from http://programmers-en.high-way.info/vb/aes.html:

```
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Text
    Imports System.Security.Cryptography
    ' 128bit(16byte)IV and Key
    Private Const AesIV As String = "!QAZ2WSX#EDC4RFV"
    Private Const AesKey As String = "5TGB&YHN7UJM(IK<"

    Private Function Encrypt(text As String) As String
        ' AesCryptoServiceProvider
        Dim aes As New AesCryptoServiceProvider()
        aes.BlockSize = 128
        aes.KeySize = 128
        aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesIV)
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesKey)
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
    
        ' Convert string to byte array
        Dim src As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text)
    
        ' encryption
        Using enc As ICryptoTransform = aes.CreateEncryptor()
            Dim dest As Byte() = enc.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length)
    
            ' Convert byte array to Base64 strings
            Return Convert.ToBase64String(dest)
        End Using
    End Function
    
    Private Function Decrypt(text As String) As String
        ' AesCryptoServiceProvider
        Dim aes As New AesCryptoServiceProvider()
        aes.BlockSize = 128
        aes.KeySize = 128
        aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesIV)
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesKey)
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
    
        ' Convert Base64 strings to byte array
        Dim src As Byte() = System.Convert.FromBase64String(text)
    
        ' decryption
        Using dec As ICryptoTransform = aes.CreateDecryptor()
            Dim dest As Byte() = dec.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length)
            Return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(dest)
        End Using
    End Function
```

Comment: `if I decrypt a small string (about 20 characters) a 100.000 times on a fast notebook that takes about 12 seconds (timed with .net StopWatch).` that's a pretty bad way of benchmarking anything, easily affected by anything else that may be running on the machine. You didn't post your benchmark code but I suspect it may be affecting the total duration as much as the code itself. Careless allocation of strings for example will waste time both in memory allocation *and* garbage collection.

Comment: If you want to gather reliable measurements use a library like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet). It won't just run each test a lot of times, it will ensure the data is statistically valid and stable. It will also gather memory and GC metrics.

Comment: Try it with AesManaged, it doesn't use the FIPS-certified unmanaged encryption libraries and much less likely to be affected by intrusive security code.

Comment: Thank you Panagiotis, good to know how to benchmark more accurately!

Comment: Thank you Hans I will try that, even disregarding exact benchmark measurements I see that AesCryptoServiceProvider in my use case leads to a very sluggish and poor user experience so good to try this alternative!

Comment: BTW converting from/to Base64 *does* generate temporary strings that need to be allocated and garbage collected. That's 200K temporary strings. The methods count the time needed to convert the unchanging IV and Key data to bytes. Why measure that? That's irrelevant. These should be byte arrays stored in fields, not parsed over and over again. All this things affect the measurements

Comment: @DotNETFan you haven't provided any exact measurements or anything that suggests that AesCryptoServiceProvider is slow or any `poor user experience`. Just a number without the test code and two encryption methods copied from an extremely old site that do a lot of things *besides* encryption and decryption

Comment: Panagiotis yes I realize now that I may not be measuring just purely the encryption/decryption but also garbage collection of a ton of strings and conversions from strings to byte arrays, BASE64 conversions etc. Will look at how to measure more accurately with BenchmarkDotNet haven't used it before.

Comment: Currently the key is stored as a string, keys should never be put into strings.

Comment: Yes of course I have not implemented this sample code in that manner, key is stored encrypted.